# clojure contrib logging to file

Tags: logging, clojure, log4j, clojure-contrib

Hi I have tried logging with clojure contrib but to no avail. 
Its clojure 1.1

```
(ns com.class.main.service
 (:gen-class)
 (:require (clojure.contrib [logging :as log])))

(log/info "Hello world")
```

I have put a log4j.jar file in my bin and a log4j.properties in the same directory as the log4j.jar.

Below is the log4j.properties conifguration

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=H:\\log\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -  %m%n*
```

I have gone through some basic examples although they are limited due to most using the newer version with tool.logging.

But below are the examples i have used

https://github.com/macourtney/Conjure/wiki/How-to-use-logging
&
http://www.paullegato.com/blog/setting-clojure-log-level/
have helped me get this far the log prints out on the console of emacs but i can't find a log file anywhere.

Comment: Why not use `tools.logging`?

Comment: its not distributed with the version of clojure 1.1.

Comment: Do you have `org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12` dependency set in your project file? Don't know exactly which version will do for clojure 1.1

Comment: I have the following in my classpath slf4j-api-1.6.0, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0 and log4j-1.2.6. The question is how does contrib.logging work with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLojure logging has three options commons-logging, log4j-logging, java-logging and it picks them in that order according to availability as per the  [document specification](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.logging) . After looking at my sources it showed the same however the compiled version was a completley different order it started with java-logging. So I simply recompiled my contrib with ant to match the order i required as i couldn't remove java-logging.

Answer (score 1):

I see that commenters have mentioned the excellent `tools.logging` library. `clojure.contrib.*` is deprecated code, and Clojure 1.1 is ancient. The toolset you are looking for, if it ever existed, is now long unmaintained and likely unsupported.

One option is to backport `tools.logging` to Clojure 1.1 if you are stuck with 1.1 for some unfortunate reason. Otherwise, you should upgrade to Clojure 1.5.1 and then you can use the current libraries & post-contrib ecosystem.